# empty state in next-redux-wrapper

Tags: javascript, redux, next.js, server-side-rendering, next-redux-wrapper

i've been having troble getting my nextjs app to work with getServerSideProps() for server-side-rednering. i tried implemening next-redux-wrapper but the state is empty.

*note: redux works fine while it was running on client side, but now im trying to get the state in `getServerSideProps()` and pass it into the component, so it renders on the server.

[image: empty state]

store.js:

```
const reducer = combineReducers({
    productList: productListReducer,
    categoryList: categoryListReducer,
})

const middleware = [thunk]

const makeStore = context => createStore(reducer, composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(...middleware)))

const wrapper = createWrapper(makeStore, {debug: true})

export default wrapper
```

reducer.js:

```
export const productListReducer = (state = { products: [] }, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case HYDRATE:
            return {...state, ...action.payload}
        case 'PRODUCT_LIST_REQUEST':
            return { loading: true, products: [] }
        case 'PRODUCT_LIST_SUCCESS':
            return { loading: false, products: action.payload }
        case 'PRODUCT_LIST_FAIL':
            return { loading: false, error: action.payload }
        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

_app.js:

```
import wrapper from '../redux/store'

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return (
    <Component {...pageProps} />
  )
}

export default wrapper.withRedux(MyApp)
```

index.js:

```
import wrapper from '../redux/store'

export const getServerSideProps = wrapper.getServerSideProps(store => ({req, res}) => {
  const state = store.getState()
  const { products } = state.productList

  return {props: {products: products}}
})


export default function Home({products}) {

  return (
    <>
      <div>{products}</div>
    </>
  )
}
```

Comment: I have the same issue. Any updates on this question?

Comment: @Afsanefda i got it working using getInitialProps with next-redux-wrapper

Comment: Thanks for responding. Is it possible to upload the code if you can ?

Comment: Any news?? I'm still facing this issue.

Comment: @Afsanefda hi i posted an answer for what worked for me.

Comment: @FelipeCandalCampos hi i posted an answer for what worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

page.js:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
return {
  listProducts: bindActionCreators(listProducts, dispatch),
  listCategories: bindActionCreators(listCategories, dispatch)
}

}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        products: state.productList.products,
        loading: state.productList.loading,
        categories: state.categoryList.categories,
        loadingCategory: state.categoryList.loading
    }
}

CategoryScreen.getInitialProps = wrapper.getInitialPageProps((store) => async () => {
    await store.dispatch(listProducts())
    await store.dispatch(listCategories())
})
  
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(CategoryScreen)
```

reducer.js:

```
import { HYDRATE } from "next-redux-wrapper"

export const categoryListReducer = (state = { categories: [] }, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case HYDRATE:
            return {...state, ...action.payload}
        case 'CATEGORY_LIST_REQUEST':
            return { loading: true, categories: [] }
        case 'CATEGORY_LIST_SUCCESS':
            return { loading: false, categories: action.payload }
        case 'CATEGORY_LIST_FAIL':
            return { loading: false, error: action.payload }
        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

store.js:

```
const combinedReducer = combineReducers({
productList: productListReducer,
categoryList: categoryListReducer
})

const reducers = (state, action) => {
    if (action.type === HYDRATE) {
      const nextState = {
        ...state,
        ...action.payload
      }
      return nextState
    } else {
      return combinedReducer(state, action)
    }
}
const bindMiddleware = (middleware) => {
  if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {
    const { composeWithDevTools } = require('redux-devtools-extension')
    return composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(...middleware))
  }
  return applyMiddleware(...middleware)
}

export const makeStore = (context) => {
  const store = createStore(reducers, bindMiddleware([thunk]))
  return store
}

export const wrapper = createWrapper(makeStore, { debug: true })
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).